# Including static assets from modules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying out the (as of now) latest version of vue-cli and ran into a problem importing static assets. My setup is pretty much a default fresh project with nothing but vuex selected and my first goal was to get a boring template with semantic ui running. This also implies jQuery with semantic ui depending on it.

To this end I added this script section to the main App.vue

```
<script>
    require('~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
    require('./semantic/dist/semantic.js');
</script>
```

..following the URL transformation rules explained [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/assets.md). My (partial) folder structure is:

```
node_modules
    jquery
        dist
            jquery.min.js
src
    semantic
        dist
            semantic.min.js
```

Running `npm run serve` does find semantic but not jquery. Can someone tell me why this proposed method of including static assets does not work in this case?

**Edit for clarification:** My question is explicitly about this proposed method of importing and the URL transformation rules. For anyone needing **some** method of getting this to work I am currently using this as a workaround:

```
<script>
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
    require('./semantic/dist/semantic.js');
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `webpack`. There is another method to includes jQuery as global variable using `ProvidePlugin`. You can add to your `webpack.base.conf.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

If you're using Eslint, you need to add to `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    "$": true,
    "jQuery": true
  },
  ...
```